# What maven artifact contains org.netbeans.core.NbErrorManager

Tags: netbeans-7, netbeans-platform, maven-nbm

I'm converting a netbeans platform build to maven, and I'm failing to identity the Maven artifact for org.netbeans.core.NbErrorManager. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.netbeans.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>org-netbeans-core</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE71</version>
</dependency>
```